# Ugly UV unwarpping in a simple case. What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: uv

I'm trying to unwrap a very simple model of a building. It unwraps fine except for the foundation of the building, where the angles between the edges are not kept.(screenshots below).

[image]

Why does Blednder fail in such a simple situation? And how to prevent this ugly unwraping?

The.blend file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3nlz9xy7mujttz6/Appartments%202.blend?dl=0).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try applying the scale (Ctrl A), then re-unwrapping

Comment: Try removing doubles(W > *Remove Doubles*). Also could you post your .blend?

Comment: Actually I do think this is a bug. Please try to report it [here](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug). A quick and dirty way to temporarily fix it is to select the bottom face only, then switch to the Bottom Ortho View, then **U** > **Project From View**.

Comment: Removing doubles and applying the scale does not help. I used method of Leon Cheung which gives acceptable result (just required to scale bottom face). Thank you all for help. I will report this as a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Reselect all your faces and try **Smart Uv Project**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I know about this method and used it in previous model. Unfortunately it cuts model in its own, so I forced to move faces and islands after unwarping to get desired look. It also seems not keeping proportions of faces which can be a big problem when texturing the model.